# Issue logging in before starting the test in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

Every time I start a test and enter the authentication data then press the login button, the page refreshes automatically and I have to restart the test so that this does not happen a second time.

I added the following feature that helped the test not log out while running. What else can I do?

```
 beforeEach(() => {
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('ASP.NET_SessionId', 'sessionid', 'chatToken')
    })
```

Comment: You can implement a custom command and call it for each test separately or use this beforeEachHook

Comment: Can you help me with more details or with a code sequence, please?